# tensorflow birectional lstm state dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, state, dimension

I am using batch_size=100 and n_units=74. When the following code is run, the `rnn_state_fw` returns (1,2,100,74). I can understand that 100 is for batch_size and 74 is for state_size, but what does 1 and 2 refer to?

```
forward_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0,1.0),state_is_tuple=True),input_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob_lstm_input,output_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob_lstm_output)

backward_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(hidden_size,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0,1.0),state_is_tuple=True),input_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob_lstm_input,output_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob_lstm_output)

forward_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([forward_cell for _ in range(num_layers)],state_is_tuple=True)

backward_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([backward_cell for _ in range(num_layers)],state_is_tuple=True)

initial_forward_state = forward_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)

initial_backward_state = backward_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)

rnn_output, rnn_state_fw,rnn_state_bw = tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn(forward_cell,backward_cell, rnn_input,initial_state_fw=initial_forward_state,initial_state_bw=initial_backward_state,sequence_length=self.seq_lengths)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LSTMCell` objects are set to `state_is_tuple=True` so the state is a `LSTMStateTuple` with two elements `(c, m)`, where `c` is the cell state and `m` is the hidden state (often denoted `h`, e.g. in `BasicLSTMCell`).

Both `c` and `m` have shape `(batch_size, num_units)`, and there are `num_layers` in the `MultiRNNCell`. So the state dimensions for the directional cells are `(num_layers, 2, batch_size, num_units)`

A good walk-through of LSTMs is of course [Colah's Blog](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/), and some explanation of why they have both a hidden and cell state can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-hidden-state-h-different-from-the-memory-c-in-an-LSTM-cell).

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I will go through the link.